# ABAP CDS view entities expression type IS_NULL not allowed in the BOOLEAN expression context

Tags: abap, sap-gateway, cds

I would like to use the is null expression in where clause of a CDS view entity. It says that expression type IS_NULL is not allowed in the BOOLEAN expression context.

I joined (left join) a table and want to assure that the joined result/fields are null, so no match.

In CDS entities the same can be applied. The fields of the joined table with no match are null and can be checked in the where clause.

```
define view entity ZI_EntityExample
  as select from    aufk
    join            afko as orderheader on orderheader.aufnr = aufk.aufnr
    left outer join jest as status      on  status.objnr = aufk.objnr
                                        and status.stat  = 'I0009'
    {
      key aufk.aufnr as OrderId,
          aufk.objnr as ObjectId
    }
    where
      status.stat is null
```

As shown in the example I would like to select out the confirmed orders via join or association.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the relevant CDS entity and your query, as well as some information about your system.

Comment: Hi Jonas. I included the example it runs on S/4HANA 7.5.

Comment: I can successfully activate this View on a 773 Kernel (probably a few versions ahead of yours)